# How can I store multiple strings mapped to an address in Smart Contract (solidity)?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I want to save multiple files in Ipfs and store its hashes mapped to an user address. I thought of having an array mapped to address and pushing to it, but does not seem to be the right approach. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have to use an array. You could use a mapping inside a mapping of some sorts but the problem is that you can't iterate over a mapping so you would have no way of knowing what hashes you have stored - unless you already know the hashes in which case storing them here is pointless. So you need something like `mapping (address => string[]) private hashes;`.

Depending on your real use case there might not even be anything wrong with using an array; in some cases deletions and inserts may pose problems but as there's generally no reason to delete an IPFS hash (the IPFS network doesn't guarantee deletion of a file if I remember correctly) and as the order of the hashes doesn't probably make a difference for you you can just always append to the array. And iterating over the array is trivial.

Comment: Instead of string[] you can use bytes32[] since it will be a ipfs hash